# Rails. Check if ANY of the attributes in a collection is blank

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a collection of invoices. One of the attributes is exchange_rate (is used to calculate the currency from US dollars for Mexican pesos). I need to create a warning if even ONE of the records doesn't have an exchange_rate set.

I could check if the exchange_rate of a record in a collection is blank like this...

```
<% is_blank = false %>

<% @invoices.each do |invoice| %>
  <% if invoice.exchange_rate.blank? %>
    <% is_blank = true %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>

<% if is_blank %>
  shoot warning: all of the invoices must have an exchange rate in order
  to calculate pesos total
<% end %>
```

What is a more Railsy way of writing the above?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply like this, using the [`Enumerable#any?`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/any?) method:

```
<% if @invoices.any? { |i| i.exchange_rate.blank? } %>
  shoot warning: all of the invoices must have an exchange rate in order
  to calculate pesos total
<% end %>
```

Comment: As usual, the answer lied in the question :) +1